# Copy ec2 files to local

Tags: magento, amazon-ec2, xampp, mysql-workbench, rds

I would like to create a local copy of a live Magento website, so that I can test and develop on my local version.

I did the following so far:

- installed XAMPP for Mac OS X 1.7.3;
- created a blank database;
- installed MySQL Workbench 6.0 for Mac;
- tried to connect to AWS EC2 and RDS instances via SSH following this scheme http://thoughtsandideas.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/monitoring-and-managing-amazon-rds-databases-using-mysql-workbench/;
- but I can't connect (it says authentication failed but credentials are correct).

Maybe there's a simpler way to create a copy of my files on EC2 and RDS and run them locally?Or maybe am I just missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is are the steps that you have to fallow to create a development site in your local pc

1. Zip all the magento files

   zip -r magento.zip /var/www/
2. Make a dump of the RDB

   mysqldump -u  username -p [database_name]  -h rbs-Endpoint  > dumpfilename.sql
3. Download the files to your local pc

   Use sftp to download all the files and check the security groups to 
   make sure the ssh port is open
4. Import the RDB to the database that you create locally

   Before restore the db pls check this http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/restoring_a_backup_of_a_magento_database

   mysql -u username  –p  [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
5. Unzip the files in your pc and move to your local webserver
6. Change the site url  http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/update_site_url_in_core_config_data or http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/restore_base_url_settings
7. Update the magento local.xml with your local database access credential
8. Clean the magento cache

BUT, My recommendation is to create a development site in another EC2 in Amazon AWS

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! I'm quite of a beginner and I'm missing one piece: in which shell do I have to type the commands? I have installed MySQL Workbench and XAMPP on a Mac OS X. I realize my question is quite dumb, but I don't want to make mistakes, so where do I type for example the first command: zip -r magento.zip /var/www/ ? Thank you very much PS My idea would be to first create a local copy of Magento where I can experiment a bit and then work on the dev environment we already have on EC2, or create another copy of it.